# how to group by terms count in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following document mapping

```
{
  properties: {
    id: {
      type: 'keyword'
    },
    rel: {
      type: 'nested',
      properties: {
        type: {
          type: 'keyword'
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the end I want to plot a x-y chart where x axis is count of type t1 and y axis is count of type t2, so for the following documents

```
{ id: 1, rel: [ { type: t1, ... }, { type: t1, ... }, { type: t2, ... }] }
{ id: 2, rel: [ { type: t1, ... }, { type: t1, ... }] }
{ id: 3, rel: [ { type: t1, ... }, { type: t1, ... }] }
```

will map to 3 (x, y) points (2, 1), (2, 0), (2, 0), and I'm going to plot them on x-y plane like this

```
^
|
|   1 
+---2-->
```

Right now I use the following aggregation

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "aggregations": {
    "g1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "rel": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "rel"
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "filter-t1": {
              "filter": {
                "terms": {
                  "rel.type": [
                    "t1"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "filter-t2": {
              "filter": {
                "terms": {
                  "rel.type": [
                    "t2"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to get the following result

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "g1": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "rel": {
            "doc_count": 4942,
            "filter-t1": {
              "doc_count": 6
            },
            "filter-t2": {
              "doc_count": 20
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "2",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "rel": {
            "doc_count": 3039,
            "filter-t1": {
              "doc_count": 6
            },
            "filter-t2": {
              "doc_count": 11
            }
          }
        }
        ...
```

and calculate number of documents in each coordinate in API layer.

The problem is that number of total documents is at millions of documents level, querying all in a request doesn't work. I don't find a way to do pagination in aggregations either, `from` `size` seems only work for _source.

Is there a way to achieve what I want in elasticsearch?

Comment: The way I would approach the problem is to store the number of type1 and type2 in two new fields at the root level and not have to mess with the nested structure at query time. After that you query becomes very simple and can leverage doc values easily.